# Style of hijack button missing

Tags: django

I have:

In `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
..
    'hijack',  # django-hijack
    'compat',
..
}

...

# django-hijack
HIJACK_USE_BOOTSTRAP = True
HIJACK_DISPLAY_ADMIN_BUTTON = False  # Since we force it manually in the admin
```

In `admin.py`:

```
...

# Since we have custom UserAdmin, we need to do special things for django-hijack
# See here: http://django-hijack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/


from hijack.admin import HijackUserAdminMixin

admin.site.unregister(User)

class CustomUserAdminWithHijackButton(HijackUserAdminMixin, CustomUserAdmin):
    """
    We are subclassing HijackUserAdminMixin to display the hijack button in the admin.
    """
    list_display = CustomUserAdmin.list_display + ('hijack_field', )

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdminWithHijackButton)
```

The link is showing in the admin, but the styles are wrong (no button). Why could this be?

[image]

(And other minor changes for the hijack notification bar, which do not affect the admin)

Comment: It looks like you are using `django-grapelli` for the admin theme. I imagine that's why you aren't getting the styles

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: right, I am using grappelli, but I have another site with grappelli and hijack, and it shows the button just fine ...

Comment: @Sayse: grappelli is first, but so is in the other project ... grappelli must be first, according to the grappelli manual.